# Fragment inside viewpager inside recyclerview blank rows on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Hi i'm trying to add a Recycler view in my app which contain view pager as row and inside view pager there are two pages which are in xml itself.

recycler view loads only user visible rows when creating fragment but when i scroll recycler view it turns blank and does not show card view contained in recycler view row (View pager) except page indicator of view pager.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: You probably don't set specific 'else' statement for some part of code. Look closely into your code and check when it's happening.